# Automapper date to string conversion not working

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper (via DI) in an asp.net core 2.0 project.

My view model has a string date property which I want to map to my DateTime property on the entity model.

I don't want to specify a global mapping profile for string to DateTime, I want to specify it for each property.

This is my mapping profile:

```
CreateMap<JobDetailViewModel, JobDetail>()
            .ForMember(x => x.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s.StartDate)))
            .ForMember(x => x.EndDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s.EndDate)));
```

This generates an exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have cut and paste my exact string into a console app running `Convert.ToDateTime(dateString)` and it works fine so I think this must be a problem whith how I defined the mapping.

I also tried:

```
CreateMap<JobDetailViewModel, JobDetail>()
            .ForMember(x => x.StartDate, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(s => { return Convert.ToDateTime(s.StartDate); }))
            .ForMember(x => x.EndDate, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(s => { return Convert.ToDateTime(s.EndDate); }));
```

But that didn't work at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to build small sample that mimics your functionality and it works for me:

```
class Source
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

class Dest
{
    public DateTime Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ForMember(d => d.Bar, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s.Foo)));
        });

        var src = new Source { Foo = "01/01/2017" };
        var dst = Mapper.Map<Dest>(src);
        Console.WriteLine(dst.Bar);
    }
}
```

Only way for me to get exception you mentioned is to indeed put bad date format (e.g. date first on US locale) into string:

```
var src = new Source { Foo = "30.01.2017" }; // European date format, will fail
```

So I would debug what exactly you are passing in and you can fix that by using `DateTime.ParseExact` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and passing exact string, e.g.:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ForMember(d => d.Bar, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.Foo, "dd.mm.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

You can pass more than one format into the method.

Comment: I am coding for US production server but I think my local European settings were being used.  ParseExact() is the right solution.  Thank you very much